# MongoDB counting very slow

Tags: python, database, mongodb, pymongo

I am using pymongo and I have a collection containing 1.2 million documents.

```
db.posts.count_documents({'$and': [{'created_at': {'$gte': start_date}}, 
                                   {'created_at': {'$lte': end_date}}]})
```

Where start and end dates are input from the user on the frontend page. For small result matches, this executes very fast but if the query matches 80~100% of the documents, it takes 500 ms which is too long.

I have made sure that the field 'created_at' is indexed. Is there anyway I could speed this up? I will be performing many counting queries on a single user click for statistics which could match a large portion of the documents contained in the database and those 1.2 million documents are only testing data, the expected size is much larger. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look [On-Demand Materialized Views](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/materialized-views/)

Comment: try running that with `explain` to see what it is doing